# OkHttp só funciona no Lollipop

Tags: android, lollipop, okhttp

A biblioteca OkHttp 2.6.0 não funciona em versões anteriores à 5 do Android.
Em versões anteriores à Lollipop sempre dispara a exceção:

**Exceção**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util
>                                                          at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.java:58)

**Meu build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 14
    versionName '1.6.7'
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  signingConfigs {
    release {}
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
  }
  productFlavors {
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile project(':number_picker_lib_2')

  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
  compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Estou usando a mesma versão que você! E não tive nenhum problema até o momento! A versão mais baixa que testamos aqui é a 4.0.3. Segundo a documentação: **OkHttp supports Android 2.3 and above. For Java, the minimum requirement is 1.7.**

Comment: Isso que é o mais estranho pois tenho outro aplicativo que funciona de boa também. Do nada parou de funcionar. Parece-me que foi após a atualização do Android Studio e a Build Tools.

Comment: Eu tive um problema com o a appcompat-v7. Subi a versão e ele não encontrava... Pra solucionar, removi o Android Studio, Baixei de novo e reinstalei! Aí fico de boa!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você deixou de adicionar o `Okio`, uma outra biblioteca que o `OkHttp` precisa para funcionar, [de acordo com a documentação oficial](http://square.github.io/okhttp/):

> You'll also need Okio, which OkHttp uses for fast I/O and resizable
>   buffers. Download the latest JAR.

Adicione o `Okio` em seu `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
```

Comment: Já adicionei. Mas a mesma exceção é lançada.

Comment: @Luídne já tentou dar um `clear project`?

Comment: Isso também já tentei.